# Magic constant to solve NP-complete problem in polynomial time

Tags: time-complexity, polynomial-time, np-complete

Let's suppose that $P\ne NP$. Is that possible to solve all the instances of size $n$ of an NP-complete problem in polynomial time using some "universal magic constant" $C_n$ that has a polynomial length $P(n)$?
Clearly, if $P\ne NP$ this constant can be only calculated in exponential time and the calculation must be done for each $n$.

Thanks

Comment: Scott Aaronson gave a good overview of these kinds of ideas in his Quantum Computing since Democritus: http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec7.html

Comment: If you're only looking at inputs of size n, everything is O(1), with the constant just being the maximum runtime over the (finite) set of inputs.

Comment: It is not at all clear that "if P!=NP this constant can be only calculated in exponential time". $\hspace{.38 in}$ It could take something between polynomial time and exponential time. $\hspace{1.61 in}$

Comment: This may answer your question UNIVERSAL EQUATION - Proof of P=NP
https://www.academia.edu/8809357/UNIVERSAL_EQUATION_-_Proof_of_P_NP

Answer (score 34):

Probably not. What you are asking is whether NP $\subset$ [P/poly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/poly). If this were true, then the polynomial hierarchy would collapse (this is the [Karp–Lipton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%E2%80%93Lipton_theorem)), something that is widely believed not to happen.

Comment: To expand a little, such a universal constant is called (polynomial) advice, and the class of languages which are decidable in polynomial time with access to polynomial advice is called P/poly.